# Tornado AsyncHTTPClient fetch callback: Extra parameters?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I'm sort of new to this whole async game (mostly been a Django guy), but I was wondering: how can I pass extra parameters to Tornado's AsyncHTTPClient.fetch callback? For example, I'm tracking the number of times a callback has been called (in order to wait until a certain number have executed before working on the data), and I'd like to do something like:

```
def getPage(self, items,iteration):
    http = AsyncHTTPClient()    
    http.fetch(feed, callback=self.resp(items,iteration))
def resp(self, response, items, iteration):
    #do stuff
    self.finish()
```

Comment: Why do you need to track the number of times the callback has been called?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to "bind" your additional arguments.
Use functools.partial, like this:

```
items = ..
iteration = ..
cb = functools.partial(self.resp, items, iteration)
```

or you could use lambda, like this:

```
cb = lambda : self.resp(items, iteration)
```

(you probably need to add the signature to def resp(self, items, iteration, response):)

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome, and exactly what I was looking for, but I've rewrote the program without async, as I sort of realized it's not necessary for what I'm doing (aggregating data on RSS feeds). Still, I'm sure I'll use this again!

Comment: I was considering a closure, but this seems to be cleaner way.

Comment: Note to others: I found that the `functools.partial(self.resp, items, iteration)` approach needed `response` to be the last param in the callback signature. e.g. `def resp(self, items, iteration, response):`

Comment: @MechEthan you can always check the positions of arguments by `def resp(*args): print args`

Answer (score 0):

you might also consider the [gen.coroutine](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html) decorator if you're calling fetch from inside a RequestHandler.  in that case, you have no need to add extra parameters to the callback because you have the result visible in the same scope as the call to fetch.

Comment: "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes."