# Tornado, Accessing additional data in callback function?

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado, asyncmongo

I have just started a project using Tornado, and asyncmongo.

I have a handler with an async method.  Inside I am querying mongo for some words:

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def get(self):
    word = self.get_argument('word', None)
    if not word:
        self.write('{}')
        self.finish()
    self.db.spanish_dict.find({'$or': [{'word': word}, {'stem': word}]},
                              callback=self._on_response)


def _on_response(self, response, error):
   # need to sort response by relevancy
```

In my callback method I need the original word to sort the mongo results accurately.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117920/tornado-asynchttpclient-fetch-callback-extra-parameters) post which uses `functools.partial` to accomplish this, by allowing me to pass additional parameters to the callback method

**I was wondering if there are any adverse affects to setting an instance attribute in the `get` method and accessing it in `_on_response`?** THank you

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def get(self):
    word = self.get_argument('word', None)
    if not word:
        self.write('{}')
        self.finish()
    self.word = word
    self.db.spanish_dict.find({'$or': [{'word': word}, {'stem': word}]},
                              callback=self._on_response)


def _on_response(self, response, error):
   # need to sort response by relevancy
   # will self.word always be accurate?
   self.word
```

Comment: No expert on tornado, but maybe `functools.partial` might help you here; filling in word as an argument to the callback function, leaving the rest to be supplied by the actual callback?

Comment: it is very helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117920/tornado-asynchttpclient-fetch-callback-extra-parameters, recommends it as the suggested way to pass additional arguments

Comment: Use tornado.gen and you sidestep the problem completely: http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/gen.html?highlight=tornado.gen#tornado.gen

Comment: @andyboot it looks like that will do it! if you want to answer i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tornado.gen and you sidestep the problem completely

http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/gen.html?highlight=tornado.gen#tornado.gen